# Invalid identifier on database link when add new column in table

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-link

I have 2 database

- DB1 with user a with ip address 192.168.10.5
- DB2 with user b with ip address 192.168.10.6

in DB2, I have existing table called `tb_r_system`

I create database link in DB1 to get table `tb_r_system` in DB2

```
  CREATE DATABASE LINK test_db_link
    CONNECT TO user00 IDENTIFIED BY user00
    USING 'RED_SERVICE';
```

then I alter add new column in `tb_r_system` , `TEST_COLUMN`. after that when I try to select from DB1 with

```
select * from tb_r_system@test_db_link;
```

it show result with new column, `TEST COLUMN`

but when i try to get this new column in package it show error

> `ORA00904 L Invalid identifier`

my package in DB1

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg_acatestw IS

  FUNCTION test_db_link(test IN VARCHAR2) 
    RETURN PLS_INTEGER;

  END pkg_acatestw;/

  CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg_acatestw IS

      FUNCTION test_db_link(test IN VARCHAR2) RETURN PLS_INTEGER IS
       tar INTEGER;
      BEGIN

        SELECT COUNT(test_column) -------------> this line cause error invalid identifier
        INTO tar
        FROM tb_r_system@test_db_link dual;

        RETURN 1;
    EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RETURN 1;
    END test_db_link;

END pkg_acatestw;
```

I'd appreciate any help

Comment: The FROM clause looks wrong, DUAL shouldn't be there.

Comment: Dual here will not create any problem, it will become table alias for tb_r_system@test_db_link. @nirwan: check where select count(test_column) from tb_r_system@test_db_link dual is working in sqlplus!!

Comment: Just to confirm, does the ORA-00904 message explicitly refer to `"TEST_COLUMN"`? When you added the column did you force a mixed-case name perhaps; can you show the exact `alter` statement you used, and `desc tb_r_system@test_db_link`?

Comment: sorry for my late response

[(at) San] even I remove dual alias, it had same error

[(at) Ales] Poole yes it refer to TEST_COLUMN. ORA-00904: TEST_COLUMN : Invalid Identifier.
My Alter script :
ALTER TABLE tb_r_system
  ADD (
  TEST_COLUMN VARCHAR(3000)
  );
========================================
It strange
Error was gone when I try to create new database link 
with different alias test_db_link2

But I worried if that is not a best solution

Thanks for all your help

Comment: weird, I having same problem

Comment: @nirwan `database link with different alias test_db_link2 But I worried if that is not a best solution Thanks for all your help` - that was the solution for me. Thank you man!